# How to modify Laravel Jetstream login ? I'd like user to redirect to Admin Dashboard when usertype is 1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-jetstream

I'm using Larave10 Jetstream livewire and I wanna modify the login.
But my code doesn't work properly what I thought.

This is user database.
Id, name:varchar(255), email:varchar(255), usertype:varchar(255), photo:varchar(255), address:varchar(255)

## What I wanna do is

1. Check usertype 0:user 1:admin
2. usertype 0 -> dashboard
   1 -> Admin Dashboard

## Home Controller

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\User;


class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function redirect() {
        $usertype = Auth::user()->usertype;

        if($usertype == '1') {
            return view('admin.home');
        } else {
            return view('dashboard');
        }
    }
}
```

## RouteServiceProvider.php

```
       class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public const HOME = '/redirect';

    public function boot(): void
    {
        RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(60)->by($request->user()?->id ?: $request->ip());
        });

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::middleware('api')
                ->prefix('api')
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        });
    }
}
```

## Web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
    
Route::middleware([
    'auth:sanctum',
    config('jetstream.auth_session'),
    'verified',
])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    })->name('dashboard');
});

Route::get('/redirect', [HomeController::class, 'redirect']);
```

Where should I modify ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php`

First add `dashboard` suffix

### RouteServiceProvider.php

```
{
    public const HOME = '/home';
    public const DASHBOARD = '/dashboard'; // new url aside from HOME
```

### RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                if (Auth::user()->usertype === 1) {
                    return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::DASHBOARD); // to dashboard
                } else {
                    return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME); // to home
                }
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

This will redirect to https://localhost/dashboard if usertype === 1 else it will be to https://localhost/home. Redirection happens when you login

This is because of middlelware `RedirectIfAuthenticated` was added in `app\Http\Kernel.php`

### app\Http\Kernel.php

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ...
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        ...
    ];
```

Comment: Btw this file names might be different in jetstream but it should be close to what you want.